# vb.net - WebBrowser1.Navigate tries to download JSON file

Tags: vb.net, json, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I am trying to navigate to a website with json data using the webbrowser controls but it keeps prompting me to download the file instead of properly navigating to the page as firefox would.

I have tried doing a regular navigate:

```
 frmBrowser.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://us.wowarmory.com/auctionhouse/money.json")
```

As well as editing the header content type with many different types:

```
frmBrowser.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://us.wowarmory.com/auctionhouse/money.json", "", Nothing, "Content-Type: text/plain" & vbCrLf)
```

But cant seem to get it working.. Keep in mind I need to use the webbrowser to navigate as you have to be logged in to access this file.

Edit: Also, manually editing my computers registry won't work as I need to distribute this program.

Edit2: Just wanted to add that this code would work if it were the same session, but since it webclient creates a new session it doesn't work

```
Dim oWeb As New System.Net.WebClient()
oWeb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Dim bytArguments As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(params)
Dim bytRetData As Byte() = oWeb.UploadData(url, "POST", bytArguments)

Return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytRetData)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application will allow it, just rename it to money.json.html or something similar. Will download without a problem.

Comment: Have you tried any other computers? See if they all handle it the same? Otherwise, I was working in VB.Net Express 2010, try upgrading. The express version is, of course, free.